# When using React-native, why does my iPhone or emulator hang with a white screen unless Chrome Debugging is on?

Tags: ecmascript-6, react-native

When running an app using react-native `0.4.4`, I see that the app will hang the iOS emulator or the phone unless Chrome Debugging is turned on. Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

I'm not getting any errors at all on Chrome when I open it. I have noticed that the "sample" React-native app doesn't have any problems when running without Chrome, so it seems like it's something within my own code, but I have no idea what!

Answer (score 0):

I took the react-native example code and started adding code from my existing project to it one file at a time until I found the offending line.

Here it is:

```
render: function () {
      let buttonStyle = styles.disabledLgButton;
      let buttonTextStyle = styles.disabledLgButtonText;
      if (this.state.submitEnabled) {
          buttonStyle = styles.activeLgButton;
          buttonTextStyle = styles.activeLgButtonText;
      }
```

It took me a while to figure it out, even when I was staring at the code that was breaking things.

I have gotten into the bad(?) habit of using certain ecmascript 6 features such as `let`. Chrome will deal with `let` without any difficulty, but the JavaScript engine on the phone chokes. As soon as I changed those `let` lines to `var`, the phone was happy rendering on its own without Chrome's help.

Comment: Wait, is it not all transpiled to es5? (so that let --> var internally anyway)

Comment: React Native has gone to `babel` internally for all transpiling since `0.6.0`, so this may no longer be an issue.